# SwitchMaterial set checked immediately

Tags: android, material-components-android

I have following `SwitchMaterial` component:

```
<com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
     android:id="@+id/my_toggle"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
```

On activity creation, I want to set the switcher to true/false, based on the database value:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     //***
     myToggle.setChecked(defaultValue);
}
```

The problem is, that when the activity is created, I can see the component to toggle to the state that I set. Is it possible to set the state immediately - without running toogle animation? For example, in [this third party library](https://github.com/kyleduo/SwitchButton), it can be achieved by `setCheckedImmediately()`. However, I can see no such option in `SwitchMaterial`.

Comment: Use `myToggle.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState()` to cancel the animation.